# trying to remove the appearance border inside my input ReactJS & Tailwind

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to remove the appearance border inside my input. But I am unable to remove it. Someone please guide me how can I remove it? I am using TailwindCSS and React JS.

You can see an inner border in the picture attached

This is the link to codesandbox: ([Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tailwind-playground-forked-pfdwmp?file=/src/App.tsx:0-904))

My code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, ChangeEvent } from "react";


export default function App() {
  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState("#1C4B40");

  const handleColorChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let inputValue = event.target.value;
    if (!inputValue.startsWith("#")) {
      inputValue = `#${inputValue}`;
    }
    setSelectedColor(inputValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-500">
      <input
        id="colorPicker"
        type="color"
        style={{
          WebkitAppearance: "none",
          appearance: "none",
          backgroundColor: selectedColor,
          borderColor: selectedColor,
          outline: "none"
        }}
        className="h-8 w-8 cursor-pointer rounded-[4px] border-none"
        value={selectedColor}
        onChange={handleColorChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdvCV.png)

I am trying to remove the inner grey border from the input. I want to achieve it using tailwind

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfGCY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this into your index.css file

```css
.swatch-wrapper {
  &::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
  }

  &::-webkit-color-swatch {
    @apply border-2 border-transparent rounded-[4px];
  }
}
```

After use the class in your code

```html
<input
    id="colorPicker"
    type="color"
    className="swatch-wrapper h-8 w-8 cursor-pointer appearance-none rounded-[4px] border-none bg-none"
     value={selectedColor}
    onChange={handleColorChange}
/>
```